# QGIS, polygons and GPS

Tags: qgis, gps

I intend to use QGIS 3.6 as a tool for archaeological field works, live tracking.

I have created a form and everything works great except for creating polygons. I have installed QGIS on a Panasonic FZ-G1, Windows 10, and use an external GPS. Points and lines work well with GPS.

When I try to create polygons with GPS, everything works well until I finish the polygon, then a break point ends at the equator, which is completely wrong. If you then validate the polygon, the result is that it is not closed. I have tried several older versions of QGIS, I have tried different GPS receivers and tried on different computers and with different projections. The error is the same.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail on the workflow. How do you finish the polygon?

Comment: I choose the edit on my polygon layer. Then I add track points around the area I want to measure. Then I click on Add Polygon, the form comes up. When I then close the form, the wrong polygon is created.